# change ant.zip() output directory

Tags: java, gradle, ant, zip, build.gradle

I want to store output of `ant.zip()` inside build directory. I'm doing it the following way for now.

```
ant.zip(destfile: sourceDirectory.name + ".zip") {
    fileset(dir: sourceDirectory.path)
}

ant.move(todir: "$project.buildDir" + "/zip") {
    fileset(dir: "$project.projectDir", includes: "*.zip")
}
```

Is there way to directly do it in `ant.zip()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
ant.zip(destfile: "$project.buildDir" + "/zip/" + sourceDirectory.name + ".zip") {
    fileset(dir: sourceDirectory.path)
}
```